# problem with numpy array operation in python

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to solve a problem from an online programming site. My code is running perfectly on my laptop. when I submitted, it is showing memory error.

```
from itertools import product
import numpy as np
t = int(input())
for T in range(t):
    n = int(input())
    a = np.arange(1,n+1)
    p = product(a,repeat=2)
    per = list(p)
    v = a.reshape(1,n)
    s1 = np.array(list(zip(*per))[0])
    s2 = np.array(list(zip(*per))[1])
    f = ((s1*s2).reshape(n*n,1))%v    #memory error here
    print((f==0).sum())
```

How can I rectify the error?

Comment: did you print out any of the intermediary variables to check what they are?

Comment: yes! I did. can you answer this, I need answer very urgently.

Comment: try computing `f = ((s1*s2).reshape(n*n,1))` first and then slice it by lengths of n  and compute `slice%v` and then concat all your answers.

Comment: MemoryError shows up when you are trying to allocate too much space. If your program really needs it, there's not much you can do in terms of debugging. Also, this is not your personnal tech support forum, and people will answer as quickly as your question if properly asked and written